# JTable.print() does not print all columns

Tags: java, swing, printing, jtable

I try to print data from JTable with this code

```
table1.print();
```

But problem is that it prints just first 7 columns.There are 10 columns at all.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: did u try printall? as far as i know java only renders the visible part usually

Comment: You're going to need to show us some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Printing modes are responsible for scaling the output and spreading it across pages. You can print your table in one of the following modes:

`table1.print(PrintMode.NORMAL);` **OR** `table1.print(PrintMode.FIT_WIDTH);`

Have a look [How to Print Tables.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/printtable.html)

Answer (score 1):

Give a try to this line of code: `table1.print(PrintMode.NORMAL);`